# Button pressed Image background set from Drawable folder Array

Tags: android, imageview

```
enter code here



public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button1;
        final ImageView image;

        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);


        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                for (int j = 1; j < 6; j++) {
                    int res=getResources().getIdentifier("d002_p00"+j,  "drawable",getPackageName());
                    image.setBackgroundResource(res);
                    }
            }
        });


    }

}
```

I have 6 image but this code only show's my first and last image.
It shows no error what can i do?
How i can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Your code shows only first and last image, because the loop in click listener goes through all images without stopping and refreshing UI. If you wish to change image each time you click, you should add a counter and increase it on each click, not 6 times in one click.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
int img=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button1;
    final ImageView image;

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);


    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            img++;
            img%=6;
            int res=getResources().getIdentifier("d002_p00"+img,  "drawable",getPackageName());
            image.setBackgroundResource(res);
        }
    });


}
```

}

Comment: how can i do that. @Zielony

Comment: how i can do that. @Zielony

Comment: see the sample I've just added

Answer (score 0):

put your all images in drawable folder.

```
  public class MainActivityextends Activity {
int counter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button1;
    final ImageView image;
    counter = 0;
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            counter++;
            counter%=6;
            if(counter==0)
            {
                image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image1); 
            }
            else if (counter == 1)
            {
                image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image2); 
            }
            else if (counter == 2)
            {
                image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image2); 
            }
            else if (counter == 3)
            {
                image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image2); 
            }
            else if (counter == 4)
            {
                image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image2); 
            }
            else if (counter == 5)
            {
                image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image2); 
            }

        }
    });

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your loop like this... but i didn't checked it.

```
//Declare this in global
 count=1



  button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           if(count>6)
               count=1;

            int res=getResources().getIdentifier("d002_p00"+count,  "drawable",getPackageName());
            image.setBackgroundResource(res);
            count=count+1;


        }
    });
```

Comment: Are you finishing your activity when you set bg?